# Stackdriver with PHP Lumen on Google App Engine Standard

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-platform, lumen, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

my purpose is to manage the logs of my application with Google Stackdriver. The application is a lumen 5.8. Actually it works locally, but if deployed on my Google App Engine application it doesn't give back any error, but no logs are reported. There the steps:

1. **Install Google Cloud package**

```
composer require google/cloud
```

2. **Create my Stackdriver logger class**

```
<?php

namespace App\Logging;

use Google\Cloud\Logging\LoggingClient;
use Monolog\Handler\PsrHandler;
use Monolog\Logger;

class CreateStackdriverLogger
{
    /**
     * Create a custom Monolog instance.
     *
     * @param  array  $config
     * @return \Monolog\Logger
     */
    public function __invoke(array $config)
    {
        putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . config('google.service_account.filepath'));

        $logger = LoggingClient::psrBatchLogger('app');
        $handler = new PsrHandler($logger);

        return new Logger('stackdriver', [$handler]);
    }
}
```

3. **Create my config file logging.php in my app/config folder**

```
<?php

use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\SyslogUdpHandler;
use App\Logging\CreateStackdriverLogger;

return [

    'channels' => [
        'stackdriver' => [
            'driver' => 'custom',
            'via' => CreateStackdriverLogger::class,
            'level' => 'debug',
        ],
...
```

4. **Register my loggin.php config file in app/bootstrap/app.php**

```
$app->configure('logging');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. The problem was in my **php.ini** :

```
extension=grpc.so
extension=protobuf.so
extension=mongodb.so
```

removing **grpc.so** and **protobuf.so** it turned back to work properly